# Setting my variable, do I use the dot notation or ~?

Tags: environment-variables, variable

All my Hadoop configuration files are located in the following:

```
./.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/etc/hadoop/"
```

To set my HADOOP_HOME variable, do I use the dot notation or ~?

```
HADOOP_HOME = "./.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/etc/hadoop/"
```

or

```
HADOOP_HOME = " ~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/etc/hadoop/"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, shell assignments do *not* allow a space before or after equal sign. Both your suggestions would actually try to run a command literally called `HADOOP_HOME`.

The relative one isn't a good idea—relative paths are relative to the current working directory, not your home directory. So if you've `cd`'d into `~/Documents`, then that would mean `~/Documents/.linuxbrew/…`. Not at all what you want.

The second one doesn't really work either, because of how quoting works. Expanding `~` is something the shell is expected to do—it generally shouldn't actually make it into an environment variable. But by quoting it, you've prevented that expansion. You need to leave the `~/` bit out of the quotes, or alternative use `$HOME` (which will expand inside double-quotes. So, either of these should work (at least if `$HOME` is set to your home directory, which it almost always is):

```sh
HADOOP_HOME="$HOME/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/etc/hadoop/"
HADOOP_HOME=~/".linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/etc/hadoop/"
```

Personally, I find the first one easier to read. There is a third option—you don't actually need any quoting here; there aren't any special characters in the name. So this is fine (and perfectly readable) too:

```
HADOOP_HOME=~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/etc/hadoop/
```

Remember to export the variable as well (`export HADOOP_HOME`).